# How to set base font sizes in Bulma CSS for responsive design

Tags: css, fonts, responsive-design, font-size, bulma

Going through the [Bulma.io documentation](https://bulma.io/), I cannot find how to set the base font-size for the responsive design.

As per [this section on setting initial variables](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/variables/), we can set the initial value of classes `$size-1` etc. However, I am wanting to set the very base font-size for the responsive-design. I.e. when the screen dimensions are, say, 980px, the base font-size should be 12px, instead of the standard 16px. Because the above mentioned font classes '$size-1', are `rem`, they would automatically resize as well.

So, my question is, is it possible to set the base font-size for the responsive design in Bulma? Or must I change the sizes of the classes `$size-1` etc manually.

Thanks

Comment: The helper class is called `body-size` within 'Generic Variables' section. See this: https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/variables/#generic-variables & also this: https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/1963

Answer (score 5):

Add this after importing Bulma SASS files.

```
html {
  font-size: 12px;
  @include tablet {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  @include desktop {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

This overrides the $body-size variable, but it's only used to set *html {font-size}* so this should not cause any problems.

Answer (score 3):

It's the [`$body-size` variable](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/variables/) that you were looking for. Before importing Bulma, customize the variable's value:

```
// Custom config
$body-size: 14px !default;
// Standard Bulma
@import "bulma/bulma.sass";
```